# Why can't java.util.Random be injected ?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

When injecting java.util.Random into a Bean, deployment fails:

> CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Random with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject myPackage.MyBean.random

Question: Why can't an instance of the java.util.Random class be injected ?

I created a class A with similar properties (like having a final method with default visibility) that injects without problems. Here's the code:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped 
public class MyBean implements Serializable { 
  @Inject private java.util.Random random;   // (R) 
  @Inject private A a; 
  ...
} 

public class A implements Serializable { 
  int n; 
  public A() { System.out.println("A"); }
  public A(int n) { this.n = n; }  
  final int nextInt(int bound) { return bound -n; } 
}
```

If line (R) is commented out, everything deploys and runs fine.

Comment: Do you have a producer for `java.util.Random`?

Comment: No. I just want the container to apply the no-arg constructor of Random.

Comment: Then you need to declare a producer that creates the instance of the class.

Comment: But why works injection for class A ? There is no producer, too.

Comment: Are you sure your class `A` is not a CDI bean?

Comment: A is surely a CDI bean, because it's a concrete class and has a no-arg constructor (cf. 3.1.1 of the CDI 1.2 spec). But  the same holds for the Random class.

Comment: To add one more piece of missing information.  The CDI spec actually mandates the default exclusion of everything in `java.*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot inject `java.util.Random` as a bean because your application does not recognize any bean or producer of that given type.

You have `beans.xml` with discovery `all` - meaning CDI will go over classes *within your application* and turn them into beans if possible (if they meet the requirements set by CDI specification). `java.util.Random` is **not** withing your application and hence CDI knows no way to instantiate such bean for you and throws an exception. On the other hand your `A` bean is within your application and since you have discovery to `all` and it meets the requirements, CDI will consider it a bean (of `@Dependent` scope with `@Any` and `@Default` qualifiers).

To be able to inject `java.util.Random`, you need to tell CDI how to do that. You can achieve that fairly easily with a producer method. Note that producer method must be declared inside CDI bean in order for CDI to find it.

```
@Produces
@Dependent //choose desired scope, or none and it will be dependeny
// you can also add qualifiers, optional
public Random produceRandom() {
  return new Random();
}
```

With the above producer, CDI will not detect it and be able to create such object when you need to `@Inject` it.

Answer (score 1):

For a class to be discovered as a bean, it has to be deployed in a bean archive, see http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive

As far as I understand, this also includes something like target/classes, but *not* the contents of rt.jar.

As I think that your question is only about the general mechanics and not about "how-to-inject-Random", I'll leave it at that. See the other answers on how to make Random injectable by a producer method.

Answer (score -1):

Your class has to be discovered by CDI as a bean. For that you have to do something like this:

Put a bean defining annotation on it. As @Model is a stereotype it's why it does the trick. A qualifier like @Named is not a bean defining annotation, probably the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Neither A nor java.util.Random has a corresponding annotation. The question is: Why can (an instance of) A be injected but Random not ? I should add that I've an empty beans.xml file in the WEB-INF directory for instructing the container to discover CDI beans.